# Fix blue screen of death on VMware Workstation

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, vmware-workstation

I just recently setup a vmware workstation for Windows XP, however it seems about twice per day I get the blue screen of death.

Unfortunately I was not able to write down the error displayed in the BSOD because it only shows for part of a second and disappears. I was able to scavenge through the vmware logs though and found some logs that appear to be errors from around the same time it occurred.

```
2014-04-13T00:44:53.109-03:00| mks| I120: MKS switching absolute mouse off
2014-04-13T00:44:53.110-03:00| vcpu-0| I120: Guest: SVGA_MINI: SetPowerState: VideoPowerShutdown
2014-04-13T00:44:53.111-03:00| vcpu-0| I120: Guest: SVGA_MINI: Cleaning up global driver state...
2014-04-13T00:44:53.142-03:00| vcpu-0| I120: UHCI: HCReset
2014-04-13T00:44:53.212-03:00| mks| I120: MKS disabling SVGA
2014-04-13T00:44:54.172-03:00| vcpu-0| I120: SVGA: Sync FIFO with SVGA disabled
2014-04-13T00:44:54.313-03:00| mks| I120: WinBSOD: ( 1) `STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}                                             '
2014-04-13T00:44:54.313-03:00| mks| I120: WinBSOD: ( 2) `The Windows SubSystem system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x'
2014-04-13T00:44:54.313-03:00| mks| I120: WinBSOD: ( 3) `c0000005 (0x75e9ad23 0x00c7f240).                                               '
2014-04-13T00:44:54.319-03:00| vcpu-0| I120: CPU reset: soft (mode 2)
2014-04-13T00:44:54.319-03:00| vcpu-1| I120: CPU reset: soft (mode 2)
2014-04-13T00:44:54.320-03:00| mks| I120: WinBSOD: ( 4) `The system has been shut down.
```

Anyways, I have 4GB of ram on the host machine, and 1GB allocated to the VM workstation. I have a dual core processor and the workplace is using both cores, however I am not running much for programs on either.

Do you guys have any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Try to run whocrashed to analyse the logs and kill the bit that's causing bsod [enter link description here](http://appuals.com/blue-screen-of-death/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to disable automatic restart on system failure. To do so, open your control panel. Switch to classic view if you aren't already there. Then open System. Then click on the advanced tab. Find the Startup and Recovery section and click on settings. Uncheck 'Automatically Restart'. This will allow you to gather more information on the cause of the BSOD's.

Note, though, that Windows XP has passed its end of life. If you have to run it, you'll want to make sure you disable networking in VMWare to make sure Windows XP can't access the Internet. You can do so by pulling down the VM menu and selecting Settings. Then remove the network adapter. This does not guarantee you can safely run Windows XP, as your installation could silently be corrupted via a number of other avenues. But it's the minimum you should consider as an acceptable first step.

Comment: Thank you for the great information! Maybe I will try to get a Windows Vista or 7 image instead. It will be easier than troubleshooting these issues too. And you think that Windows XP won't work properly with networking enabled? The networking is actually the main reason I'm using Vmware is so I can utilize two different ISPs (I have two modems and two routers in my home and both connected to one PC). Will networking work fine on Vista or 7? Or any recommendations there?

Comment: XP has passed its end of life. The networking isn't broken, but XP is no longer safe to use. Far better that you go for Windows 7 as that is still supported. Some people may recommend Windows 8.1, but I'm not a fan.